# jQuery grab html

Tags: jquery, attributes, extract

We have `link` to some page (with html code, on the same domain), that page have one `img`, which attributes `title` and `alt` are equal.

Script must open `link` (no showing on the page), grab the `src` attribute of `img` which `title=alt`, and throw the `value` into some `variable`.

Is it possible to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the page on the same domain, or a different one?  If it's on a different domain then you're out of luck.

Comment: on the same, like grabbing http://site.com/item/ from http://site.com/works/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/),  like this:

```
$.get('/works', function(data) {
  var src = $('img', data).filter(function() { return this.title == this.alt; })
                          .attr('src');
  dosomethingWithIt(src);
});
```

This is an asynchronous operation, so that function will execute and get the `src` when the response comes back, it won't be available in the line of code after the [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).  You need to continue whatever operation needs that info from within that function, so it continues working once the data comes back and is ready.

Comment: you are a star :) Will try to implement in hours

Answer (score 2):

$.get(link, function(data) {
      variable = $(data).find('img[title="same"][alt="same"]').attr('src');
    });

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery: on that specific page

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var link = $('img').attr('src');
    var title = $('img').attr('alt'); // or $('img').attr('title');    
});
```

Comment: This grabs attribute but don't open a page with link. As far as I could understand OP needs open one page from another and grab something exactly there.

Comment: @abatishchev you are true, I've no access for external page

Answer (score 0):

First this will read data from external url:

```
$.get('../item/test.html', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Does it work for you? Does it display your url?